# MySql - Enable stored procedure feature access using --with-debug in Windows

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySql commandline 5.6.11 and when I try to see my stored procedure in the command line like

```
SHOW PROCEDURE CODE sp_my_procedure
```

I'm getting:

```
ERROR 1289 (HY000): The 'SHOW PROCEDURE|FUNCTION CODE' feature is disabled; you need MySQL built with '--with-debug' to have it working
```

How do I use the command to run mysql with "--with-debug" in Windows (I saw the documentation but it talks about how to do that in Linux)?

Answer (score 17):

You need to compile your mysql binary by yourself, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/source-installation.html, because of

```
SHOW PROCEDURE CODE proc_name
```

> This statement is a MySQL extension that is available only for servers
>   that have been built **with debugging support**.

But maybe [SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-create-procedure.html) gives you what you want.